# GitHub Action appleboy/ssh-action: How do I avoid that the SSH key ends up on the server?

Tags: github, ssh, web-deployment, github-actions

To log in from GitHub to my external server I use/test appleboy/ssh-action. As soon as I am on the server I start a git pull to get the latest changes to the server. However, this also includes the .github/workflows folder. And in a GH action yml file is my SSH password. I would like to avoid this. But I don't know how. Somebody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not store the password in the YAML file itself.  Instead, use the GitHub Actions secrets functionality in the repository settings to store the password as a secret, and then pass it in through the environment.  For example, you can pipe a secret like so:

```
    - run: echo $PASSWORD | my-program-here
      env:
        PASSWORD: ${{secrets.SSH_PASSWORD}}
```

You can see an example of how this kind of approach is use in the [Git LFS release workflow](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/.github/workflows/release.yml).